# Don't you think being "God-like" would be awfully boring?

Tags: theology, philosophy-of-religion

If you knew everything there would be nothing left to learn.
If you could do anything, there would be no challenges left to tackle.
If you were everywhere at once, there would be nothing left to discover.
If you had everything, there would be nothing left to desire.

Now imagine this reality for eternity.
Wouldn't this be infinitely boring?

Comment: I think this question can be philosophically tackled: Heidegger, Pascal, Cioran, Nietzsche and Schopenhauer wrote about boredom. Countless philosophers about god. I don't think, that this needs to be primarily opinion based...

Comment: Wouldn't being a rock be infinitely boring? Or a tree?

Comment: Most people spend most of their lives not really doing much of those things anyways.

Comment: I have offered something of a reconstruction of this question -- see the history -- please do feel free to expand or reframe or even roll back, but just in passing the more specific a problem you can pose (that is in terms of a real obstacle in your study of philosophy) the more likely you are to get a great answer :) Welcome to Philosophy and thanks for the question

Comment: On the contrary, I find being God-like constantly rewarding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all.

First, God aside, we cannot attribute human characteristics to non-humans.  Do you think it would be really boring to be a paramecium, or a cow?  I see no reason one should.  And I don't think the reason is that we are somehow superior to them.  I don't find humans who crave excitement to be more intelligent, or even more interesting, than couch-potatoes with vivid imaginations.  The former constantly imagines the latter is bored.  Even from the standpoint we are God's image, we cannot attribute too many of our biological drives onto him.  An image is not a duplicate, it has attributes of its medium that the original lacks.

But in the end, there is a good reason for humans to get bored, we have limited lifespans and cumulative memories.  Filling up that memory with experiences that are not all related increases your likelihood of discovering things and moving us all forward.  That would not apply to God.

In particular, from a traditional Roman Catholic point of view God causes time, and would not be subject to it, by the likes of Augustine, who translates 'eternal' as 'extra-temporal' he wouldn't even experience it.  That would remove the possibility of boredom in a very complete way.

For certain other forms of Christianity, like C.S. Lewis' "Mere Christianity", at some point God had to be bored, but that can't be too common.  The need to be everything good is why it was necessary for God to be incarnated.  Otherwise, relative to humanity, he would have the "Mary" experience from "Mary's Room" (q.v. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_argument), but not the "real" experience.   And to be truly omniscient, he must fully relate to all forms of experience.  (The natural Gnostic extension is that this is why Satan is also necessary, and is also God.  It is quite mandatory, from a pretty common human point of view, that God understand completely what it is like to be evil, if he is going to judge evil humans fairly.)

So in some sense, God was just dying to get bored, it must have been new and exciting for him!

Comment: But God never changes, the bible says so in `Malachi 3:6` "For I am the LORD, I change not". `Numbers 23:19` "God is not human, that he should lie, not a human being, that he should change his mind. Does he speak and then not act? Does he promise and not fulfill?". `Psalm 102:27` "But you remain the same, and your years will never end.". One can argue that by being paramecium or a cow lack one will lose  self awareness. And self awareness is the key to boredom, you will not be bored if you don't even aware of what you're doing. I don't find breathing boring because I'm not even aware of it.

Comment: But I like to believe that God is self aware. And self awareness + static state of being = boredom.

Comment: Not if you control time directly.  There is a very cute habit in Niven's Science Fiction, of making immoral AI's have to keep editing out meaningless time so that they don't become bored with enough with anything to have that affect their functioning.  If God can just remove time that does not matter from his experience pro-actively, he never has to wait for anything, or tolerate any event he would rather pass by.

Comment: Except it would be impossible for God to just remove information from His mind, because there is no other space that isn't come from Him, any space, time and information comes from Him and is **maintained** by Him alone. He knows everything and everything to come. He won't learn anything new and also won't forget anything. Besides, you said "God was just dying to get bored, it must have been new and exciting for him". So in your mind you kinda think that new experience (being bored) is valuable. This indicates that you also think that experiencing something new is favorable.

Comment: Being the cause of something does not make one subject to its limitations.  You have cause and effect reversed.  There is no logic here.

Comment: You said "If God can just remove time that does not matter from his experience pro-actively, he never has to wait for anything, or tolerate any event he would rather pass by.". I said, God can't just remove the time because He maintains it. Where did the reasoning go wrong again?

Comment: You ignored the "pro-actively" -- he can just keep anything from happening that would bore him.  There is bound to always be something amusing going on somewhere in the universe.  I don't care to keep defending myself, you have no interest in taking the argument seriously.

Comment: I'm sorry did I upset you? Defending yourself or your idea? You're anthropomorphising God (I do too btw), you see Him as though He experiences time like we do (because you said "something amusing **going on** somewhere"). Well I think God is different, He doesn't feel the time as we do. The idea of Him being bored is exactly because of that, because He is static. Nothing NEW is going on, He sets everything in motion but He Himself doesn't change at all. To Him we're just motion pictures He created and He remembers everything exactly as it is.